# Can I use harvested plants to gain electric power?

Tags: electrochemistry, home-experiment

I was just thinking - plants are mostly acid. Even grass is quite acid. Could you create battery cell from squashed plants (after cutting them in pieces)?

How much effective would it be? Could you compare it to solar panels? Would you need to replace electrodes often?

Comment: Are you thinking about a battery (i.e. rechargable) or a simple galvanic cell?

Comment: Rather a "refillable" battery - when the power is low, you remove old plants and put in a new ones. Imagine a electric device that feeds on grass...

Answer (score 3):

A company in the USA called [Voltree Power](http://voltreepower.com/) has gone one step further to harvest electricity generated directly from live trees and other plants!

It seems trees are able to provide somewhere between 20 and a few hundred millivolts as well as some current, derived from a difference in pH between the trees and the soil, maintained by the trees metabolic processes.

The science behind this technology was [published in 2008 by researches at MIT](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0002963).

The company claims to have [demonstrated the technology](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/06/25/idUS230976+25-Jun-2009+BW20090625) by developing the first wireless sensor network powered exclusively by trees to detect forest fires! They are also developing the technology to monitor humidity and temperatures in the forest using electrical power harvested from the trees themselves and transmit the data using low-power wiremess mesh technology.

Another collaborative group from University of Michigan, MIT & UC Berkeley [published their research](http://scitation.aip.org.proxy.library.adelaide.edu.au/content/aip/journal/apl/95/1/10.1063/1.3157144) in 2009 into micro-power electricity scavenged from evaporative flows within the microchannels in trees.